# Would Birds Wear Corsets?

Tags: humanoid, clothing, avian

Corsets are a type of clothing which are typically worn to support and shape the waist and torso. While this makes sense for soft-bellied mammals, the benefits to other classes are hard to figure

Birds, in particular, have very rigid bodies; their ribcage encompasses their entire torso to the hips, and the ribs connect together firmly

This seems like it would make corsets rather redundant for avian beings. While corsets could perform other functions besides shaping, these also seem plausibly achievable without a corset, especially on the hard avian body

Would avian beings actually benefit from wearing corsets? Or would they simply not need to bother?

Comment: What are "avian beings"? Do you mean our common birds but intelligent? Humanoid bipeds but covered in feathers? Something in between?

Comment: @KeizerHarm Humanoids with avian anatomy

Comment: corsets are made to support the spine not to squish sosft bellies. The only difference between a terapeutic lumbar support for children with spinal problems or herniated adults and an actual corset is that the corset is sold as a vanity item.

Comment: better question would they wear clothes,  most animals are not hairless like us.

Comment: Corsets **only** serve fashion purposes. Even in terms of "support functionality" for women, modern brassieres are objectively superior in terms of maintaining comfort, support, and mobility when compared to a corset (also birds wouldn't have breasts). That said, people will do *anything* for fashion, including wearing garments which are highly impractical or unnecessary, so it's not impossible.

Comment: @IchthysKing "Humanoids with avian anatomy" is a contradiction, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another important feature corsets/bodices/stays did, was to spread the weight of heavy dresses and skirts to the whole body from shoulders/waists. A lot of women that reconstruct the fashions of 17-19 centuries would tell you that those costumes are tiring without the corset or with a badly fitted one, but quite comfortable, when done properly.

Now, boning - inserting rigid elements of bone or metal - was not always a necessary part of the corset, just several layers of heavy non-elastic fabric were used.

Your avian humanoids would not need boning in their corsets, since their torso is rigid already, but if they have a fashion of heavy multi-layered dresses and skirts, they would certainly benefit from the weight distribution of a well-fitted boneless bodice.

Comment: But doesn't a skeleton that differs greatly from that of humanoids necessitate a concept quite different from a corset? The way the weight is distributed depends on where what forces come into play, which will be different, if only because their postures are completely different.

Comment: Since OP specifies them as both avian and humanoid, I'm not quite sure what that means for their lower torso and leg attachment. The tailored non-elastic bodice would still work, I think, even if attachment points for the skirts would be situated differently.

Answer (score 15):

**Effortless puff!**

[image: pigeon]

http://pigeonsinsideandout.weebly.com/pigeon-info.html

Dude looks good, no?  Pigeon males puff out their shiny green neck feathers when they are trying to impress.  But that takes focus and it is easy to get distracted.  Keeping it up can be difficult.

Tech can help!  Pigeon corsets keep that fluff fluffed so even if the male is distracted or starts thinking about taxes or his lumbago is acting up, he will be looking virile and baby daddy ready!

Comment: if effects last for more than 4 hours, call the doctor, they will high five you!

Answer (score 1):

**They wouldn't.**

Where would the wings go? Either under or over the corset would significantly increase drag, and impede swimming/diving and maneuvering capabilities.
Tail flicking will also be severely limited.

Sure, ostriches, emus, kiwis and other flightless birds wouldn't suffer from these particular impediments, but they would (considering a regular sized corset [i.e. when adapted to bird anatomy]) from their now restricted leg movement.

Taking into account freedom of movement, the importance of the ways forces interact with their bodies, and the rigidness of their bodies, **there are very few articles of human clothing that avian beings would consider wearing** (if they were to consider such a thing).

Comment: But wouldn't this be an argument for humans not wearing corsets? If you would tell stone age people about them, they'd probably not think they'd sound plausible for humans either. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Birds don't have boobs.

Comment: @EdvinW The anatomy of stone age people is barely different from our current anatomy, so I feel I am missing something as well :) I intended to illustrate my points, but at least my first point is not hard to imagine: anything that constricts the main body of the bird will impede their flight. And if we take a human corset - one that is tight around the waist (and positioned underneath the rib cage, insofar as that is possible on bird-like creatures) - the leg muscles and vertical movement of the tail will also be limited.

Comment: "The anatomy of stone age people is barely different from our current anatomy" My point exactly. I'm just saying corsets seriously impede human mobility as well. They make running, climbing and swimming much harder. A human not previously exposed to clothing could probably still see the point of a coat if you explained it to them, but you'd have a harder time selling a corset to a hunter-gatherer.

Comment: @EdvinW But **our lives don't depend on aerodynamics and maneuverability**, as is the case with birds, which is my point :)

Comment: @Joachim Our lives **do** depend on us running, climbing, crawling etc, activities which are hindered by corsets, at least by the tighter ones. People wealthy enough to have other people do these things for them or who rely on machines might get away with it still though. In the same way, birds not living in the stone-age (as real present day birds do) might very well get by without aerodynamics and manoeuvrability. For any animal, really, it's just a question of how comfortable their lives have to be before they can afford to wear a corset!