# Could Lizardfolk Wear Corsets?

Tags: humanoid, clothing, reptiles

Corsets are a useful piece of clothing. While they can be used to shape the body, they can also serve the purpose of supporting other clothing

While the shaping functionality is [not useful to avians](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/223736/would-birds-wear-corsets), there are other beings that need consideration, such as lizards

Like mammals, lizards have mobile ribs that can move to breathe. However, they also have a complete ribcage as in birds. This ribcage is also uniquely flexible

Given the nature of the lizard torso, could humanoid lizards wear boned corsets to shape their bodies?

Comment: i am a bit wary of your starting point, that corsets are useful. They were developed as part of the clothing for both women and men striving to appear to have the idealised body form that high society valued at the time. There was never any suggestion that they supported outer clothing .. the crinolines and petticoats under flaring skirts were structurally supportive, but only of the skirts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, they could.**

I wear a vest-styled corset with steel boning to help support a very heavy leather and brass kilt as part of a steampunk costume. This corset has boning on all sides that extends from my hips, up and over my ribcage. The boning that extends over my ribcage is what I base this answer on.

Wearing this corset allows my chest to expand, but prevents me from arching forward or backwards as far as I can without it. So, they would definitely lose some of their extra flexibility. But they would still be able to breathe and move their arms.

Answer (score 1):

**Only if you can Imagine it.**

Lizardfolk have some things in common with lizards and others in common with humans. Some things are standard. For example lizard scales and human bipedalism. Most other things are up to you, the creator.

If you wish you may declare lizard people have only partial ribcages and squishy bellies like humans. If you wish you may declare otherwise. It is up to you!

One advantage of a squishy belly is room to expand. For example to carry larger young. If I were the creator I'd err towards squishy belly lizard people giving birth to live young, or at least larger and fewer eggs than normal lizards. Of course I am not the creator. You are.

Answer (score 0):

Yor question is simply answered - of course they *could*, but why would they need to? And, why would they want to.

Corsets reduce the size of any soft part of a torso that is not supported by ribs or some other boney structure, so nearly any lizard or mammal could wear one. But one can equally well wrap a corset around a tree.

Comment: The reason is the same reason people wear corsets. To shrink the belly. The concern is lizards don't have a belly because their ribs go all the way down.