# Would Frogs Wear Corsets?

Tags: humanoid, clothing, amphibian

Corsets are undergarments with a variety of usages, including supporting large dress and such. While this is functional for [birds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/223736/would-birds-wear-corsets) and [lizards](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/229157/could-lizardfolk-wear-corsets), I feel there is another type of being to consider, that being humanoid frogs

Unlike birds and lizards, which have complete ribcages that encompass the whole torso, frogs have no ribcage at all. In particular, the humanoid frogs in my world have narrow spines, not much wider than that of a human, with shoulder blades and a humanoid pelvis without any ribs, sternum or collarbones. Their torso is otherwise humanoid in shape

Given this, would a full corset aid these frogs with supporting heavy dresses, or would their minimal skeleton make corsets do more harm than good to them?

Comment: I think the biggest issue would be with the compression of the ribcage of a frog, wearing a corset might make them.... Croak...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, was this rather bizarre question inspired by the recent (partial?) industry ban on making actresses wear corsets in period costumes?

Comment: Why do you never ask about their millinery? I want to know if the Beatrix  Potter style bonnets are a goer!

Comment: You can find out yourself by trying to wear a corset on your soft belly instead of your ribcage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would Birds Wear Corsets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/223736/would-birds-wear-corsets)

Comment: I'm confused, how can they breath without ribs to support muscles? Can you perhaps provide a diagram of their skeleton to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, just not well**

While frogs' skeletal structure wouldn't be very helpful for supporting the use of a corset, certain corsets could be made to tailor towards this weakness. A corset with perhaps a metal ribcage lining it might allow for the usage of one.

Though, while the frogs might be able to wear the corset, it wouldn't really help to support a dress, on account of the fact that their chest isn't expanded open by a ribcage like humans' are. This would mean that there isn't much more room for the chest to be compressed, constricting however much a corset could form the torso.

Answer (score 5):

### Definitely, but they squish necks, not chests

Who's never watched a 'bodice-ripper'? Those who don't have time for them because they're watching Pride and Prejudice, of course!

Now, as everyone in either of these two groups knows, while corsets are impractical, they do look great. Small waists, large, shapely breasts; you can argue that it we oughtn't like the way they look,  but they do. Nuff said. Pride and Prejudice should have been called Enhanced Sexual Dimorphism And Large Country Estates.

Frogs don't have breasts. They're decidedly lacking in that department. Nor are the frog sexes differentiated by waist width. What are frogwomen differentiated by? Their constrained vocal sacs. Female frogs don't have big macho vocal sacs. Instead, they have tiny - and very alluring, from Mr Frogley's perspective - necks.

And that's where frog corsets come in. There's nothing more attractive to Mr Fitzwilliam Darfrog than a corseted female frog neck. With bits bulging out at the top and bottom.

Naturally, this is terrible for breathing and health in general. The frogs don't care, and won't for another two centuries.

I tried putting 'sexy corseted female frog with tiny sacs and bits bulging out of corset, top and bottom, getting choked' into an AI image generator but I feel the results are not good for the moral fibre of this forum. So you will have to imagine it instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Frogs Don't Wear Heavy Clothes**

[image]

Frogs are amphibians. They breath through their skin. The skin must remain wet in order for gas exchange to work. Clothes interfere with the process by wicking moisture away from the skin. Unless the clothes are themselves soaking wet.

You want a dress heavy enough to require a human to wear a corset to support it. Imagine how much heavier the dress will be when soaking wet. You don't have to imagine. Take the duvet from your bed and fill it with water from the hose. Wrap the soaking wet duvet around yourself and proceed with your day.

Heavy isn't it?

That's what a heavy dress does to a frogman. Frogmans cannot dance in such a heavy dress. They can hardly move.

Comment: I'm upvoting this purely for a picture of Mr Toad in Gators and driving gloves about to become Toad! The terror of the highways!

Answer (score 3):

Like EducatedScribbles said, the practical reasoning for corseting to support a large dress probably wouldn't really be there due to frog anatomy, but I think that the social pressure to fit in to the standard of attractiveness like the other humanoid animal people would supercede that hurdle. Do you think women with large bodies due to genetics were granted leeway in Victorian times? NO! They had to be cinched to perfection like everyone else. Fainting couches existed for a reason.

A big thing to consider. however, is the effect of a frog's slimy mucous coating on the wearing of a corset and dress. The mucous produced through the skin would make the corset slip out of place and may undo the knots tied to keep the corset tight over time as they become soaked. Beyond that, the dress and undergarments would quickly become very damp and even heavier from the mucous seeping into the fabric, while also looking quite disgusting. You'll have to come up with some kind of creative solution for this to ensure the functionality of fabric clothes in the first place, much less corsetted dresses. Perhaps some kind of body suit?

Answer (score 2):

**Humanoid frogs as you describe have no choice but to wear corsets**

Rib cages serve more purposes than corsets, and one of them is to keep everything in place. In humans and other more-or-less upright creatures, the rib cage doesn't just contain organs, it's the framework that holds organs in place. Otherwise their own weight would pull them down, killing the creature.

How your humanoid frogs came to not have a solution to this problem (aka, a rib cage) is a bit of a mystery, but they were certainly uncomfortable and massively limited in what they could do until they saw someone wearing a corset. At that point, someone said, *chirp, rumble... croak-ribbit!* Or, loosely translated, "that looks like a good idea... here, hold my beer while I go boost that weird looking shirt."

But! They'd never wear them to hold up dresses. Not unless you've given them human-style hips.

Comment: I'm curious though, how would a humanoid frog die from their organs being pulled down? If that was the case, wouldn't the g's that they experience during a jump kill them?

Comment: @EducatedScribbles I believe most frogs don't significantly jump vertically. In a horizontal jump, the mass isn't jostled as much. But to be completley honest, I'm an engineer, not a biologist, for all I know frog organs are bound somewhere inside without the benefit of ribs. However, I have held big toads in my hands - and the organs do sink inside the animal to a degree. Now, as to the OP's creatures... I'm making no presumptions about how his/her frogs are made and little was given. If Ichtys says the organs are held in place just fine without ribs, then there's no reason to wear corsets.